# Словообразовательная цепочка слова "покоиться"

Tags: словообразование

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить словообразовательную цепочку слова "покоиться".

Comment: Пользуйтесь книгой. Она — источник знаний. Не списывайте у ретивых.

Answer (score 3):

По Тихонову:

***покой*** (отсутствие движения, спокойствие) ->

-> *покоj-**и**-ть* (суффиксальный способ образования) ->

-> *покоить-**ся*** (суффиксальный способ образования)

.

См. *Тихонов А.Н. "Словообразовательный словарь русского языка", М., 1990:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**Покой ― покоj/и/ть/ся,**  суффиксальный способ.

Глагол "покоиться" по смыслу мотивируются сущ. "покой", а "покоиться" ― это трад.-нар. форма.

ПОКОИТЬСЯ, -нсв. 1. **Пребывать в покое**, отдыхать. П. в неге, в дремоте. П. крепким, мирным, сладким сном (спать). // Высок. Быть похороненным где-л. Здесь покоится прах Иванова. В братской могиле покоятся вечным сном герои Отечественной войны.

ПОКОИТЬ, нсв. кого-что. **Трад.-нар.** Окружать покоем, заботой, почтением. П. чью-л. старость. П. отца на старости лет.

**Дополнение**

Разные варианты словообразовательного анализа объясняются   тем, что, **условно говоря,** существуют два вида анализа: **формальный и семантический.**

**При формальном анализе** мы делим слово на максимальное количество известных морфем и цепочку строим  **только с учетом существования** каждого последующего слова.

**При семантическом анализе** учитывается мотивация слов: каждое последующее слово **должно быть связано с предыдущим по смыслу**. (В этом случае возможно выделение сложных суффиксов или формантов).

Покоиться ― это пребывать в покое, а не "покоить себя",  слово "покоить" к тому же не общелитературное, малоизвестное.

Наверное, оба способа словообразовательного анализа **имеют право на существование** (но не имеет смысла говорить об их  правильности или неправильности, они просто разные).